# StatusStripLabel dynamically updated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My point is to display number of all child nodes at StatusStripLabel. My point is that I want StatusStripLabel to get updated everytime number of child nodes get's changed - I'll add or delete some of already exists. First, I placed code in `Public Form`, but it didn't worked as I expected. After some time I came with idea that actually works: I placed the code inside button method. But after that I realized that I'll need to place it in second place, in case of deleting node. So My question is: is there anything that can make it simplier? If my explanation isn't enough, just tell me, I'll try my best.

Code from `Public Form` (Because I want that counter to work from the beggining, not after I'll press the button)

```
childNodeCounter();
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " + NodeCounter.ToString();
```

Method:

```
        public void childNodeCounter()
    {
        NodeCounter = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode RootNode in treeView1.Nodes)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in RootNode.Nodes)
            {
                NodeCounter++;
            }
        }
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " + NodeCounter.ToString();

    }
```

Code inside button method:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NodeCounter = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode RootNode in treeView1.Nodes)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in RootNode.Nodes)
            {
                NodeCounter++;
            }
        }
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " + NodeCounter.ToString();
    }
```

**Edit:** Thanks to mr. Hans Passant I wrote this and it works very well:

```
        public int childNodeCounter(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode RootNode in nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in RootNode.Nodes)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
```

Event handler looks like this:

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " + childNodeCounter(treeView1.Nodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Three tiny optimizations

1. Rather that iterate the tree yourself, just use `ChildNode.Nodes.GetNodeCount`
2. Rather than repeat the same logic in different places, have your button Click events simply call the `UpdateNodeCount()` method.
3. The text initializer in the first code fragment is redundant, and can be eliminated:  the call to childNodeCounter already does the status label update.

Comment: 1."ChildNode.Nodes.GetNodeCount" works for XML only, I Think. 2.I had it before, but couldn't make it to work like I wanted to, but it's fixed now. 3.I don't save anywhere this number, so every time program launches, it has to be counted again.

Comment: 1.  WinForms TreeNode has GetNodeCount() method.   2.  Elimination of redundancy may not speed up your program, but makes it easier to understand and maintain.    3.  I don't think you understood:  When you call `childNodeCounter()` it updates the status label.   You don't have to immediately update the status label again.

Comment: 1.Now I see, you're right. It looks kinda useful, I'll implement it in future. I'm aware of that. 2.I didn't explain it well previously - after your comment I made it into method. 3.Once again, now I get it. Thanks for feedback, that type of comments I wanted to see, when I created this question.

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to traverse a tree structure is by using *recursion*.  That's always a bit hard to reason through but there are lots of resources available.  Doing it iteratively is a lot uglier, you have to use a Stack<> to allow you to backtrack again out of a nested node.  I'll therefore post the recursion solution:

```
    private static int CountNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes) {
        int count = nodes.Count;
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes) count += CountNodes(node.Nodes);
        return count;
    }
```

Then your event handler becomes:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " +
            CountNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But your code counts both child and root nodes, and my goal is to make only child nodes count.

Comment: "Child node" doesn't mean much, you might be talking about leaf nodes.  Please don't hesitate to adjust the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding and removing "game" nodes to the treeView, you must be having methods like `void AddGame(string title)` and `void RemoveGame(string title)` which add/remove (child) nodes - those whose total number you want to count. If I understood well, you want `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text` to be automatically updated each time the number of child nodes changes. In that case you can add field

```
private int nodesCount;
```

to your Form class and have something like this:

```
void AddGame(string title)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { AddGame(title); }));
    }
    else
    {
        AddGameNodeToTreeView(title); // add new game node to desired place in TreeView
        nodesCount++; // increase node counter
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Number of games in database: " + nodesCount;
    }  
}
```

`RemoveGame()` would be implemented in the same way (or joined with `AddGame()` into a single method with one additional argument - `bool add`). Both methods could be extended if you're adding/removing multiple nodes in which case you'll be passing title array and updating `nodesCount` accordingly.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to count nodes in the tree each time before updating `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text`. Also, `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text` is updated automatically, not only when user clicks the button.

Drawback is that `nodesCount` is somewhat redundant information: total number of nodes of interest is 'hidden' in the `treeView`. You have to make sure that `nodesCount` is in sync with the actual number of nodes.